# Does the Catholic Church recognize any marriages performed by a Justice of the Peace

Tags: catholicism, marriage, civil-government

Does the Catholic Church recognize a marriage performed by a Justice of the Peace?

I (Kathy) am a widow and have met a Episcopalian man (Dana) who is divorced but never married in any Church.  We were told, no problem...until tonight when we were told that if Dana's former wife was also Episcopalian that the Catholic church recognizes the marriage as valid even though it was performed by a Justice of the Peace ...BECAUSE....the Episcopalian Church recognizes marriages performed by a Justice of the Peace.

Then, to make it even more confusing, we were told that if Dana's former wife was Catholic then the Catholic Church would NOT recognize it...BUT...wouldn't the Episcopal Church recognize that marriage?

Following the logic, then the Catholic Church would equally recognize it?  Now, the real kicker is that she never practised any religion and never did Dana as an adult.  But he is a good man and he is in the RCIA program and we want to live a good Catholic life but, without him getting an annulment, we can't marry in the Church...according to what we have been told.

Please advise if what we have been told is true.

Comment: This is a confusing post. On  the one hand, you have a question. On the other hand, you gave two answers. What is wrong with your answers? The answer depends on the religion of the ex-wife, according to your post.

Comment: No, they are not recognized. You need to get a legal marriage convalidated.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. However, your question is a rather complex personal issue, and this really isn't the best place to ask about it. This is really an issue that you'll need to work out with your priest, and perhaps with the Catholic hierarchy.

Comment: Kathy, have you looked at the other questions here about Catholic marriage, remarriage, and annulment? Do any of them answer your question? If not, what's the remaining confusion?

Comment: Welcome to our site. Please take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what kind of questions work best here. This  question is based on an enquiry about Catholic doctrine, which would by itself probably be in scope for our site. But the question, in its entirety, deals with personal issues and then appears to become a request for pastoral advice, which we feel unable to offer.

Comment: I spent over six years in the RCIA program getting people into the church.  Situations like this were not uncommon.  The short answer is go through the process, and do what you need to do to get a decree of nullity, since the church sees a JP marriage as licit (legal) but not sacramentally valid.  When I figure out how to start a chat room for this question, I can chat with you on and off for the next day or two.  As Dick said, pastoral advice isn't our purpose here, and the process of nullity is something that you need to sit down with the local clergy and discuss in detail.

Comment: [An answer to a related question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/7470/24204)

Comment: @Steve This question isn't that confusing to someone who has encountered the permutations in marriages that the RCC addresses in determining valid/licit, and when a decree of nullity is called for.  But as things like this are "case by case basis" Lee's and Dick's points about the pastoral nature of the question are spot on.

Comment: [Also a related question and answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/31588/24204). This question is answerable without getting into pastoral type counselling if two questions can be answered: 1) is Dana baptized and 2) are you Roman Catholic?  An explanation on what the process of nullity is about may be a helpful addition to this site.

Comment: I am a widowed Catholic and Dana was baptized in the Episcopal Church.  Dana and his first wife did not participate in any religion.